# error computing cache key on circle-cl when I setup

Tags: reactjs, npm, circleci

**situation**

I started to React project and pushed the default project to the git remote  and connected to circle-cl
and set up and added config but the problem occurs. I don't know how to deal with this situation.

**Restoring cache**

```
error computing cache key: template: cacheKey:1:30: executing "cacheKey" at <checksum "~/project/package-lock.json">: error calling checksum: open /home/circleci/project/package-lock.json: no such file or directory
```

**installingNpm packages**

```
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2020-10-12T03_01_22_810Z-debug.log


Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the `package-lock.json` file committed in your repo

Comment: @Dominik, yarn based project don't have package-lock.json.

Comment: That is correct but please read the error message @prettydev and then know that I was just responding to that content ;) (and this can very well be an npm project ... not enough information here hey)

Comment: @prettydev I solved the problem with your advice ( added a package-lock.json)

Comment: hi, @taiga, will you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**solution**

1.npm run start

2.added package-lock.json automatically(in my case)

3.git push

4.deployed success on circleci